# What all is passed on clicking the submit button of a form?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, pug

I am using node.js with jade templating engine. I am having a form in jade as follows:

```
form.form-signin(style="padding-left:10px", action='/update', method='post')
      table.table.table-hover(style="background-color:#fff;align:center;border:1px solid #ddd;padding-left:10px")#myTable.tablesorter
        tbody
          - if (evententries.length > 0) {
            each entry, i in evententries
              tr(style="height:5;font-size:12px;")
                td(style="background-color:#5c78b2;")
                  p(style="color: #fff;text-align:center;") Team Name
                td(style="background-color:#5c78b2")
                  p(style="color: #fff;text-align:center") Presenter(s) 
                td(style="background-color:#5c78b2")
                  p(style="color: #fff;text-align:center") Master
                td(style="background-color:#5c78b2")
                  p(style="color: #fff;text-align:center") Manager
              tr(style="height:30px;background-color:#E5EDFC;color: #000;font-size:14px;align:center")
                td
                  input(type='textbox', name='teamname', value='#{entry.teamname}', style='width:120px;', readonly='readonly')
                td
                  input(type='textbox', name='presenters', value='#{entry.presenters}', style='width:120px;', readonly='readonly')
                td
                  input(type='textbox', name='scrummaster', value='#{entry.master}', style='width:120px;', readonly='readonly')
                td
                  input(type='textbox', name='manager', value='#{entry.manager}', style='width:120px;', readonly='readonly')
              tr
                td(style="background-color:#fff; vertical-align:middle")
                  p(style="white-space:pre;word-wrap: break-word;text-align:center") Write-up
                td(style="background-color:#fff", colspan="2")
                  input(type='textbox', name='writeup', value='#{entry.writeup}', style='width:120px;', readonly='readonly')
                td(style="background-color:#fff; vertical-align:middle")
                  button#edit(type='submit') Edit
```

I wish to know what all will this type of form submit as it has a table inside it with some readonly input fields.I want that on submitting the form only the input readonly fields should be passed.

Comment: [`disable`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp) the fields you don't want to send, on submit via `Jquery` or `Javascript`

Comment: Two different questions: what gets submitted, and how to restrict submission to readonly fields (which is odd—why would you want to get at data that you already know?). The first question is answered in HTML specifications. The answer to the second one seems to be that nothing needs to be done, since the form appears to contain readonly fields only, except for the submit button, which lacks a `name` attribute. So is this a real case, or is the real case more complicated.

Comment: @Ravi Does the form send all the data, that is the table data like "Team name" or only the input fields. I don't want to disable any input fields. If it sends all the data then how do I disable the other table data other than input? The example you have given shows how to disable the input fields only.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I am trying to update an existing database entry which is displayed here in the form of a table. I need to know its details so that I can identify the correct entry from the database and update it. Thus, I want to pass the readonly fields.

Comment: @AbhishekChauhan It will not send your `TD` element data, forms only send the data from `input` OR `textarea` like attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a form is submitted, the data sent consists of name=value pairs corresponding to “successful controls”, as defined in HTML specifications; see e.g. HTML 4.01 section on [controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.2) and on [form data set construction](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3). Only controls (form fields) with a name and a value can be “successful controls”. In this case, the `input` elements are successful controls, except for the `input type="submit"` element, which is not successful, since it lacks a `name` attribute. Thus, from this form, only the readonly fields get submitted.

It is however a good idea to check what really gets submitted, by constructing a simple server-side script that just echoes back what it gets and, for a test, replace the form’s `action` attribute by one that points to that script.